# Generate random number between 000 to 999, and a single digit can only occur maximum of two times

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I generate numbers that range from 000 to 999? Also, a single digit can only occur maximum of two times in the same number.

Examples of numbers I'd like to generate:

```
094
359
188
900
004
550
```

Examples of numbers I **don't** want to generate:

```
000
999
444
```

What I've got so far:

```
function randomNumbers () {
  var one = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
  var two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
  var three = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 0;

  return '' + one + two + three;
};
```

I know the code can be improved a lot, I just don't know how. Current function isn't checking if the same number occurs three times (should only occur a maximum of two).

I can use jQuery in the project.

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow is meant for doing your projects for you.

Comment: It's quite easy. We strongly believe that you can do it by yourself.

Comment: I am asking a question, answering questions is what Stackoverflow is meant to do.

Comment: have you ever test you function? did you get a digit with `9`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that will never have to retry. It returns the result in constant time and spreads the probability evenly among the allowed numbers:

```js
function randomNumbers () {
  var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 990);
  val += Math.floor((val+110)/110);
  return ('000' + val).substr(-3);
};

// Test it:
var count = new Array(1000).fill(0);
for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    count[+randomNumbers()]++;
}
// filter out the counters that remained zero:
count = count.map((v,i) => [i,v]).filter( ([i,v]) => !v ).map( ([i,v]) => i );
console.log('numbers that have not been generated: ', count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    for(var i=0; i<50;i++)
        console.log(randomNumbers ());
    
    function randomNumbers () {
        
        var one = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        var two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        var three = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

        if( one == two &&  two == three && one == three )
            randomNumbers();
        else
            return (""+one + two + three);

    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try that? It's a long while since I last attempted to do a not-equal on multiple variables, but I'm reasonably certain that it should resolve to `if (true != three)`, which is not a useful check. Though, admittedly, I haven't tested it. Also, following the edit, it doesn't prevent `one` from being equal to `three`.

Comment: doing this check `one != two &&  two != three` generates an wrong pattern where the second digit never can be equal to any of both others.  I mean, `110` can't be generated but is specified as correct

Answer (score 0):

Keeps track of what you started.

```
function randomNumbers () {
   var one = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   var two = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   var three = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

   return one==two && two==three ? randomNumbers(): '' + one + two + three;
};
```

Here the function call itself recursively up to the point where it result
meets the requirements. The probability of generating three equal numbres is 1/100 so be sure that it will recurse nearly to never.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the expected result:

```js
function getRandom() {
  var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
  var splitted = randomNo.toString().split("");
  var res = [];

  splitted.filter(v => {
    res.push(v);
    if (res.filter(x => x == v).length > 2) return false;
    return true;
  });

  while (splitted.length < 3) {
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    if (splitted.indexOf(ran) < 0) splitted.push(ran);
  }

  console.log(splitted.join(""))
    return splitted.join("");
}


for (x = 0; x<100;x++) {getRandom()}
```

Comment: what is the advantage of `+ 0` in the second line?

Answer (score 0):

You could count the digits and check before return the value.

```js
function getRandom() {
    var count = {};
    return [10, 10, 10].map(function (a) {
        var v;
        do {
            v = Math.floor(Math.random() * a);
        } while (count[v] && count[v] > 1)
        count[v] = (count[v] || 0) + 1;
        return v;
    }).join('');
}

var i = 1000;
while (i--) {
    console.log(getRandom());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If, it were me, to be more flexible, I'd write a function I could pass parameters to and have it generate the numbers like the below:

```js
function getRandoms(min, max, places, dupes, needed) {
  /** 
   * Gets an array of random numbers with rules applied
   * @param min int min Minimum digit allowed
   * @param mas int min Maximum digit allowed
   * @param dupes int Maximum duplicate digits to allow 
   * @param int needed The number of values to return
   * @return array Array of random numbers
   */
  var vals = [];
  while (vals.length < needed) { 
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    var digits = randomNum.toString().split('');
    while (digits.length < places) {
      digits.push(0);
    }
    var uniqueDigits = digits.removeDupes();
    if ((places - uniqueDigits.length) <= dupes) vals.push(digits.join('')); 
  } 
  return vals;
}

// for convenience
Array.prototype.removeDupes = function() {
  /**
   * Removes duplicate from an array and returns the modified array
   * @param array this The original array
   * @return array The modified array
   */
  var unique = [];
  $.each(this, function(i, item) {
    if ($.inArray(item, unique)===-1) unique.push(item);
  });
  return unique;
}


var randomNumbers = getRandoms(0, 999, 3, 2, 10);
console.log(randomNumbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```